# LSSerializer is missing xmlns attribute when serializing an xml document in jdk 11 (works fine in jdk 8)

Tags: java, xml, java-11

I am using LSSerializer `linked below' for serializing xml documents in my application and now that I am moving from java 8 to 11, I have seen that the serialized xml documents are missing the default xml namespace attribute ("xmlns"). It seems the LSSerializer implementation used in jdk 8 has been replaced jdk 9 onwards.
And the new implementation misses the xmlns attribute when serialising a DOM Document (a bug?)

To illustrate the issue, the following code when compiled and run in java 11 misses the xmlns attribute in xml (it works fine with java 8)

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSOutput;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.*;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xml = "<bio><body xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:xfa=\"http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/\"><p>test</p></body></bio>";
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);
            Element node = doc.getDocumentElement();

            DOMImplementationLS domImplementation = (DOMImplementationLS)doc.getImplementation();
            LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementation.createLSSerializer();
            String output = lsSerializer.writeToString(node);
            System.out.println(output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output in java8:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<bio><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/"><p>test</p></body></bio>
```

Output in java11:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><bio><body xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/"><p>test</p></body></bio>
```

I have checked this by altering different DOM Configuration properties `link below` of the LSSerializer object like "namespace-declarations", "discard-default-content",etc but it is missing xmlns attribute in all cases.

[LSSerialize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html)

[altering different DOM Configuration properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration.html)

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. Please help me if you have found any solution for that.

Comment: This issue has been introduced in Oracle JDK 8 as well (starting with update 261). Maybe it has something to do with the update to Apache Xerces version 2.12.0: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8238164

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. I fixed it by setting the namespaceAware to true, which is default false.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```